# How to get parent element of a snapshot in cloud firestore functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use a cloud firestore function to get the parent of a document. My code is as follows:

```
exports.sendMatchNotification = functions.firestore.document('/Users/{user}/matchedUsers/{match}').onWrite(async (snap, context) => {

    // get parent data

    const userRef = snap.parent.parent;

    userRef.get().then(parentSnap => {
        const user = parentSnap.data();
        const name = user.name;

        console.log('user.name => ', name)

        return null;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`Failed with error info: ${err}`);
        return err;
    });
})
```

the log says "cannot read property parent of undefined." Why is snap undefined in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the API documentation for [onWrite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore_.documentbuilder#onwrite), `snap` is a `Change<DocumentSnapshot>` object.  It's not a DocumentSnapshot itself.  You have to use either the `before` or `after` property of the [Change](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.change) object to get a [DocumentSnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html).  After that, you have to go further and use its `ref` property to get a reference that can point up to its parent collection reference.

```
exports.sendMatchNotification =
functions.firestore.document('/Users/{user}/matchedUsers/{match}').onWrite(async (change, context) => {

    const snap = change.before;
    const ref = snap.ref;
    const userRef = ref.parent.parent;
```